# Optimize Python: Large arrays, memory problems

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, large-data

I'm having a speed problem running a python / numypy code. I don't know how to make it faster, maybe someone else?

Assume there is a surface with two triangulation, one fine (..._fine) with M points, one coarse with N points. Also, there's data on the coarse mesh at every point (N floats). I'm trying to do the following:

For every point on the fine mesh, find the k closest points on coarse mesh and get mean value. Short: interpolate data from coarse to fine.

My code right now goes like that. With large data (in my case M = 2e6, N = 1e4) the code runs about 25 minutes, guess due to the explicit for loop not going into numpy. Any ideas how to solve that one with smart indexing? M x N arrays blowing the RAM..

```
import numpy as np

p_fine.shape => m x 3
p.shape => n x 3

data_fine = np.empty((m,))
for i, ps in enumerate(p_fine):
    data_fine[i] = np.mean(data_coarse[np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(ps-p,axis=1))[:k]])
```

Cheers!

Comment: is there a reason why you cannot use [nearest neighbors regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html)  in sklearn? probably much more efficient than doing it by hand.

Comment: I think numpy is not the good module to do that kind of things, because the loop over the point of the fine mesh cannot be vectorized. If you need to code it by hand, I suggest using Cython and working with explicit for loops.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `p` and `p_fine` are meshes. Since a mesh is usually structured, it would be a lot faster if you switched to a different data structure (e.g. a kD-tree) where searching for spatial data is fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all thanks for the detailed help.

First, Divakar, your solutions gave substantial speed-up. With my data, the code ran for just below 2 minutes depending a bit on the chunk size.

I also tried my way around sklearn and ended up with

```
def sklearnSearch_v3(p, p_fine, k):
    neigh = NearestNeighbors(k)
    neigh.fit(p)
    return data_coarse[neigh.kneighbors(p_fine)[1]].mean(axis=1)
```

which ended up being quite fast, for my data sizes, I get the following

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

m,n = 2000000,20000
p_fine = np.random.rand(m,3)
p = np.random.rand(n,3)
data_coarse = np.random.rand(n)
k = 3
```

yields

```
%timeit sklearv3(p, p_fine, k)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.46 s per loop
```

Comment: This seems to be the better one! Good job on researching these.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

We are working with large sized datasets and memory is an issue, so I will try to optimize the computations within the loop. Now, we can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to replace `np.linalg.norm` part and [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) in place of actual sorting with `np.argsort`, like so -

```
out = np.empty((m,))
for i, ps in enumerate(p_fine):
    subs = ps-p
    sq_dists = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs)
    out[i] = data_coarse[np.argpartition(sq_dists,k)[:k]].sum()
out = out/k
```

**Approach #2**

Now, as another approach we can also use [`Scipy's cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) for a fully vectorized solution, like so -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
out = data_coarse[np.argpartition(cdist(p_fine,p),k,axis=1)[:,:k]].mean(1)
```

But, since we are memory bound here, we can perform these operations in chunks. Basically, we would get chunks of rows from that tall array `p_fine` that has millions of rows and use `cdist` and thus at each iteration get chunks of output elements instead of just one scalar. With this, we would cut the loop count by the length of that chunk.

So, finally we would have an implementation like so -

```
out = np.empty((m,))
L = 10 # Length of chunk (to be used as a param)
num_iter = m//L
for j in range(num_iter):
    p_fine_slice = p_fine[L*j:L*j+L]
    out[L*j:L*j+L] = data_coarse[np.argpartition(cdist\
                           (p_fine_slice,p),k,axis=1)[:,:k]].mean(1)
```

**Runtime test**

Setup -

```
# Setup inputs
m,n = 20000,100
p_fine = np.random.rand(m,3)
p = np.random.rand(n,3)
data_coarse = np.random.rand(n)
k = 5

def original_approach(p,p_fine,m,n,k):
    data_fine = np.empty((m,))
    for i, ps in enumerate(p_fine):
        data_fine[i] = np.mean(data_coarse[np.argsort(np.linalg.norm\
                                                 (ps-p,axis=1))[:k]])
    return data_fine

def proposed_approach(p,p_fine,m,n,k):    
    out = np.empty((m,))
    for i, ps in enumerate(p_fine):
        subs = ps-p
        sq_dists = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs)
        out[i] = data_coarse[np.argpartition(sq_dists,k)[:k]].sum()
    return out/k

def proposed_approach_v2(p,p_fine,m,n,k,len_per_iter):
    L = len_per_iter
    out = np.empty((m,))    
    num_iter = m//L
    for j in range(num_iter):
        p_fine_slice = p_fine[L*j:L*j+L]
        out[L*j:L*j+L] = data_coarse[np.argpartition(cdist\
                               (p_fine_slice,p),k,axis=1)[:,:k]].sum(1)
    return out/k
```

Timings -

```
In [134]: %timeit original_approach(p,p_fine,m,n,k)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.1 s per loop

In [135]: %timeit proposed_approach(p,p_fine,m,n,k)
1 loops, best of 3: 539 ms per loop

In [136]: %timeit proposed_approach_v2(p,p_fine,m,n,k,len_per_iter=100)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.2 ms per loop

In [137]: %timeit proposed_approach_v2(p,p_fine,m,n,k,len_per_iter=1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 53.1 ms per loop

In [138]: %timeit proposed_approach_v2(p,p_fine,m,n,k,len_per_iter=2000)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.8 ms per loop
```

So, there's about **`2x`** improvement with the first proposed approach  and **`20x`** over the original approach with the second one at the sweet spot with the `len_per_iter` param set at `1000`. Hopefully this will bring down your 25 minutes runtime to little over a minute. Not bad I guess!