# Python compute a specific inner product on vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vector, vectorization

Assume having two vectors with m x 6, n x 6

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random(m,6)
b = np.random.random(n,6)
```

using np.inner works as expected and yields

```
np.inner(a,b).shape
(m,n)
```

with every element being the scalar product of each combination. I now want to compute a special inner product (namely Plucker). Right now im using

```
def pluckerSide(a,b):
    a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 = a
    b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 = b
    return a0*b4+a1*b5+a2*b3+a4*b0+a5*b1+a3*b2
```

with a,b sliced by a for loop. Which is way too slow. Any plans on vectorizing fail. Mostly broadcast errors due to wrong shapes. Cant get np.vectorize to work either. 
Maybe someone can help here?

Comment: So, `a` in `pluckerSide` is each row from the original input array `a`? Likewise for `b`? Could you share the loopy code that generates `a` and `b` that you are feeding into `pluckerSide(a,b)`?

Comment: a,b are Lines in plucker space, a 6-space representing geometrical lines. so each row in either a or b is a line in 3d. pluckerside computes the inner product of such 2 line, giving information on which side they pass each other in space (or if they intersect, its ==0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an indexing based on some random indices for pairwise multiplication and summing on those two input arrays with function `pluckerSide`. So, I would list out those indices, index into the arrays with those and finally use `matrix-multiplication` with [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to perform the sum-reduction.

Thus, one approach would be like this -

```
a_idx = np.array([0,1,2,4,5,3])
b_idx = np.array([4,5,3,0,1,2])
out = a[a_idx].dot(b[b_idx])
```

If you are doing this in a loop across all rows of `a` and `b` and thus generating an output array of shape `(m,n)`, we can vectorize that, like so -

```
out_all = a[:,a_idx].dot(b[:,b_idx].T)
```

To make things a bit easier, we can re-arrange `a_idx` such that it becomes `range(6)` and re-arrange `b_idx` with that pattern. So, we would have :

```
a_idx = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
b_idx = np.array([4,5,3,2,0,1])
```

Thus, we can skip indexing into `a` and the solution would be simply -

```
a.dot(b[:,b_idx].T)
```

Comment: both solutions work perfectly. thank you. right now im optimizing the rest of the code and maybe "chunk" it off since this way its using way more memory (looking at m,n in the order of 10e4 float32 - so easily crossing a few gigs)

Comment: @Max Yes chunk it as shown in the previous post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39751039/3293881